# Python : Transform Pandas dataframe containing list and dictionaries

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame in the following format :

```
vector = pd.Series(np.empty((5,5)).tolist())
frame = pd.DataFrame({'list': [["Name1"],
['Name2'],['Name31', 'Name32'],['Name4'],['Name51', 'Name52'],],
'outcome': [{'Name1': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']}, {'Name2': ['X1', 'Y1', 'Z1']}, {'Name31': ['X2', 'Y2', 'Z2'], 'Name32': ['X3', 'Y3', 'Z3']},
            {'Name4': ['X4', 'Y4']},
            {'Name5': ['X5']}]
})
frame['vector'] = vector
frame
    list    outcome  vector
0   [Name1] {'Name1': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']}  [1.76926647e-316, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1   [Name2] {'Name2': ['X1', 'Y1', 'Z1']}   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2   [Name31, Name32]    {'Name31': ['X2', 'Y2', 'Z2'], 'Name32': ['X3', 'Y3', 'Z3']}    [3.43209934e-316, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
3   [Name4] {'Name4': ['X4', 'Y4']} [0.0, 1e-323, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
4   [Name51, Name52]    {'Name5': ['X5']}   [0.0, 0.0, 8.92286664e-315, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I would like to transform in to the following format :

```
outcome vector
0   X   [1.76926647e-316, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1   Y   [1.76926647e-316, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2   Z   [1.76926647e-316, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
3   X1  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
4   Y1  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
5   Z1  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
6   X2  [3.43209934e-316, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
7   Y2  [3.43209934e-316, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
8   Z2  [3.43209934e-316, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
9   X3  [3.43209934e-316, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
10  Y3  [3.43209934e-316, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
11  Z3  [3.43209934e-316, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
12  X4  [0.0, 1e-323, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
13  Y4  [0.0, 1e-323, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
14  X5  [0.0, 0.0, 8.92286664e-315, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Would would be the best way to do it given that the dataframe size is huge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flatten the values in `outcome` to become a simple list and then "explode" it:

```
frame['outcome']= frame.outcome.apply(lambda x: [el for sublist in x.values() for el in  sublist] )
frame = frame.explode('outcome')
```